Delete the circled cell and / or clear the 2 cells to the right
I have an excel list that I past data in the far right column. If any other data matches it highlights red. I remove the red as  it indicates it is complete. I would like to automatically search out the red and delete it. However it is the two cells to the left that add together to create the red cell.

What VBA or button can I use to automatically remove the circled info?
Just removing duplicates only removes the red. But that messes up the formula needed to create that cell and shifts everything incorrectly. I either need to clear the two cells to the left and sort all data to the top or I need to delete all three cells circled and shift up.
I feel like I could some how edit this code to delete the cells to left of anything that is red.


So you ask a question, take a picture of it and ask that same question again? :-)

You could edit that code to delete the cells and what's left of it. Have you tried? It'd also be helpful to have an idea of your spreadsheet's structure, not much users can program having no context of your actual sheet beyond a column and the two columns to the left of it. Even just an example with a basic concept of what is happening and what needs to happen will go a long way for you getting a solution.

Mark - Here is the entire spread sheet (updated the original question). The roof, floor, and wall departments report to me what they built in the first several columns. (job+ jig = job jig; 11518 + A01 = 11518 A01). Then in the description column I am pasting report info of what was scanned into an inventory system. Whatever matches from what the departments reported and what shows in the system highlights as duplicates and thus is confirmed built and removed from the sheet. The non-highlighted products need to be found and scanned into the system.

Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?.
Please create MD table with online tool Table Generator

Place this Sub in the sheet's code module where the data are. This will delete the three cells and move the cells up from under the deleted cells. Take care that the characters color matches to vbRed or change that constant to the appropriate color value.
Sub red_del()
Dim cell As Range

lastrow = UsedRange.Row + UsedRange.Rows.Count
Set Rng = Range("C1:C" & lastrow & ", G1:G" & lastrow & ", K1:K" & lastrow & ", O1:O" & lastrow & _
", S1:S" & lastrow & ", W1:W" & lastrow)
Set delrng = Range("XX1:XZ1")  'dummy range to default value
For Each cell In Rng.Cells
  If cell.Characters.Font.Color = vbRed Then
    Set delrng = Union(delrng, Range(cell.Address, cell.Offset(0, -2).Address))
  End If
Next cell
delrng.Delete xlUp
End Sub




Having an issue making this work, not sure what I am doing. I changed my highlights to red as mentioned.

What happens exactly when you run the code?
